# Why when I create an enviroment with anaconda in Visual Studio Code and I try to activate it, shows me an error

Tags: python, django, anaconda, backend, conda

I try to activate the env that I already created and everything fine, but when I tried the command "conda activate whynotdata" it shows me this error:

```
PROGRAMACION\Data_base_whynot> conda activate whynotdata
usage: conda-script.py [-h] [--no-plugins] [-V] COMMAND ...
conda-script.py: error: argument COMMAND: invalid choice: 'activate' (choose from 'clean', 'compare', 'config', 'create', 'info', 'init', 'install', 'list', 'notices', 'package', 'remove', 'uninstall', 'rename', 'run', 'search', 'update', 'upgrade', 'build', 'convert', 'debug', 'develop', 'doctor', 'index', 'inspect', 'metapackage', 'render', 'skeleton', 'verify', 'token', 'pack', 'server', 'env', 'content-trust', 'repo')
```

When I create it with the anaconda prompt everything works fine but in Visual Studio Code I can't complete it, and I want to create my env on the folder that I have on Visual Studio, I am a begginer in the back-end, I am of autodidact learning.

Thank you

I am  trying to create an env on a folder that I create and then install django, I want to use Anaconda to create the project but it didn't work and is rare because on the config of my sistem I added the path to the environments of windows, of the anaconda3 and anaconda3\scripts

Answer (score 0):

You may need to make changes in conda path to make VS code recognize conda commands:

1. CTRL+SHIFT+P open “Preference: Open User Settings (JSON)”.
2. Set the “python.condaPath” variable to

   “python.condaPath”: “C:\Users\your-user-name\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe”

Answer (score 0):

For me, it takes two step

1. Set the `Python: Conda Path` variable to `[where anaconda installed]\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe` in setting
2. Set the `Terminal › Integrated › Default Profile: Windows` to `Command prompt` in setting